# Time Limit Exceeded on selecting as many non overlapping segments as possible

Tags: java

This is a question from **Coursera's Algorithmic toolbox week 3 (Collecting Signatures)**.

Given a set of  segments {[0, 0], [1, 1], . . . , [−1, −1]} with integer coordinates on a line, find the minimum number  of points such that each segment contains at least one point. That is, find a set of integers  of the minimum size such that for any segment [, ] there is a point  ∈  such that  ≤  ≤ .

In this code I have tried sorting the start array along with the end array and that takes O(n^2) complexity, which is a hell lot for n = 100. I think the logic which I have written in the function is right as it works for other small inputs.
Someone please help me out.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class CoveringSegments {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] start = new int[n];
        int[] end = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            start[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            end[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        int[] newStart = new int[n];
        int[] newEnd = new int[n];
        boolean[] done = new boolean[n];
        int k = 0;
        while (k < n) {
            int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (start[i] <= min && !done[i]) {
                    min = start[i];
                    index = i;
                }
            }
            newStart[k] = start[index];
            newEnd[k] = end[index];
            done[index] = true;
            k++;
        }
        List<Integer> list = coordinates(n, newStart, newEnd);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            System.out.print(integer + " ");
        }
    }
    public static List<Integer> coordinates(int n, int[] start, int[] end) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = end[index]; index < n; ) {
            list.add(i);
            do {
                index++;
            } while (index < n && i >= start[index] && i <= end[index]);
            if (index == n)
                break;
            index--;
            i = end[index];
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: What’s your question? Do you want us to improve your sorting algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will caution against using two arrays. You should create a new class for the starts and ends. It will look like this.

```
class OrderedPair implements Comparable<OrderedPair> {
    public int start;
    public int end;
    public OrderedPair(int start, int end) {
      this.start = start;
      this.end = end;
    }
    public int compareTo(OrderedPair other) {
      if (this.start > other.start) {
        return 1;
      } else if (this.start < other.start) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I would replace most code in main with the following.

```
ArrayList<OrderedPair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  pairs.add(new OrderedPair(scanner.nextInt(), scanner.nextInt()));
}
Collections.sort(pairs);
List<Integer> list = coordinates(n, pairs);
```

Obviously, this will require other changes to the code. You will have to change the coordinates() function. But it will have much better runtime, compared to the selection sort you are running now.